# Notifications in my .netcore 2.1 MVC deployed on Azure Linux WebApp

Tags: azure, asp.net-core-mvc, azure-web-app-service, azure-notificationhub, azure-signalr

My application is .Net Core 2.1 MVC. I am also using jQuery.
This application is deployed as an Azure Linux WebApp.

The users can see this website from desktop-based browsers like IE, Chrome, Safari etc. as well as from Iphone, IPad and Android mobile devices.

My backend's database is Azure MySQL 5.7. I have created a notification table in MySQL. The backend populates this notification table. The notification records may be applicable to a specific user or a group of users.

If a user is online, they should see the live updates (count and notification text).

Is Azure SignalR service or Azure Notification Hub the right choice for implementing this?

Answer (score 0):

Push notifications are supported for iOS, Android, Windows Universal, Windows Phone, Kindle, Android China (via Baidu), Xamarin (iOS and Android, Chrome Apps, and Safari.

Notification Hubs is primarily designed to send notifications to mobile apps. It does not provide email or text message capabilities. However, third-party platforms that provide these capabilities can be integrated with Notification Hubs to send native push notifications by using [Mobile Apps](https://azure.microsoft.com/services/app-service/mobile/).

Notification Hubs also does not provide an in-browser push notification delivery service out of the box. Customers can implement this feature using SignalR on top of the supported server-side platforms

Hope I answered your question, Gist is basically you need to use both for implementing your solution.

Comment: @MohitVermaMSFT, so what you are saying is if i use only SignalR, notifications will work in desktop browsers. To make notifications work in browser of Mobile devices like Andriod/ IPhone/ IPad  i am forced to use Notification Hub. Both SignalR and NH gets mandatory.

Comment: No signalR you can use it in both of the cases, but it doesn’t stand true for notification hub. But signalr has different limitation. Also you have to implement proper retry logic if you are using signalr to send notifications